# Recuperar arquivo de input file com Angular Js

Tags: javascript, html5, angularjs

Preciso criar um objeto com os dados de um formulário e não sei o que fazer com o input type="file". Existe alguma diretiva pronta, tipo ng-model,  que recupera o arquivo de um input type="file" com Angular Js?

Answer (score 1):

Existe sim, veja essa diretiva:
https://github.com/ghostbar/angular-file-model

Há um preview aqui:
http://plnkr.co/edit/0ZHCsR?p=preview